# continuity and measure

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $ A, B \subseteq \mathbb {R} $ be  Lebesgue measurable  sets such that at least one of them has finite measure. Let $ f $ be the function defined by
>   $$f (x) = m ((x + A) \cap B)$$
>   for each $ x \in \mathbb{R} $. Show that $ f $ is continuous.
>
> Hint: Suppose first that $ A $ and $ B $ are intervals and then generalized to arbitrary sets using the regularity of the Lebesgue measure.

Some help please. Thanks.

Comment: Can you prove it when $A$ and $B$ are both intervals?

Answer (score 1):

1. We can assume that both $A$ and $B$ are open sets of finite measure.

   Denote $f_{A,B}(x):=\lambda((x+A)\cap B)=\int_\mathbb R\chi_B(y)\chi_{x+A}(y)\lambda(\mathrm dy)$. 
   Assume without loss of generality that $B$ has finite measure. By outer regularity, there is a sequence $(O_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ of open sets such that $B\subset O_k$ and $\lambda(O_k\setminus B)\leqslant k^{-1}$. We thus have 
   $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_{A,B}(x)-f_{A,O_k}(x)|\leqslant k^{-1},$$
   and it therefore suffice to show the result when $B$ is an open set of finite measure.

   Considering $A\cap [-N,N]$ instead of $A$, we can also assume that $A$ is of finite measure. Since $f_{B,A}(x)=f_{A,B}(-x)$, we can also assume that $A$ is an open set of finite measure.
2. An open set is a countable union of disjoint intervals hence we have to prove the result when $A$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals, then use again an approximation argument.

Comment: Is this also true for $\mathbb{R}^n$?