# A different proof of Urysohn's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show Urysohn's Lemma following this approach.

Let $K\subset V \subset \mathbb R^N$, with $K$ compact  and $V$ open. Set 
$\delta= \mbox{ dist } (K,V^c)$ and take $\epsilon<\delta/2$. Define $V_\epsilon=\{x\in \mathbb R^N : 
\mbox{ dist } (x,K) < \epsilon\}$ and consider the following function
$$
g(x)=\frac{|V_\epsilon\cap B_\epsilon(x)|}{|B_\epsilon|}, \quad \mbox {where } B_\epsilon(x) \mbox{ denotes the ball centered at } x \mbox { and radius } \epsilon.
$$ 
Need to show that $g\in \mathcal C_c(\mathbb R^N)$ and that $\forall x \in \mathbb R^N$ we have  $\chi_K(x)\le g(x)\le \chi_{V}(x)$.

In fact I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What parts are difficult for you? All? Can you show that $g$ is continuous but have trouble proving compact support? Can you show $\chi_K(x) \leqslant g(x) \leqslant \chi_V(x)$ but have problems with the continuity of $g$?

Comment: I have problems with the first part: to prove that $g$ is continuous and of compact support.

Comment: Okay. It would be good to state in the question that that is the part you have problems with. I suggest addressing the support first. Can you describe the set where $g(x)$ may be $> 0$? Such a description leads to the compactness of the support easily.

Comment: I think the set where $g$ is greater than $0$ is the closure of $V_\epsilon$

Comment: It's larger than that. $g(x) > 0$ if (and only if) $V_{\epsilon} \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)$ has positive measure. Make a sketch of a simple situation, say $N = 2$, $K$ the closed unit disk and $V$ a larger disk. In that situation it's easy to see where $g(x) > 0$, and then you should get an idea how to show that it's analogous in the general case.

Comment: Oh, I think it should be $\bar{V_\epsilon}+B_{\epsilon}(0)$

Comment: Yes (no need to take the closure of $V_{\epsilon}$ by the way, since $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ is open), or we can also describe it as $V_{2\epsilon}$ (however, it would have been better to call the set $K_{\epsilon}$ rather than $V_{\epsilon}$ since $V$ only enters into its definition by giving a bound to the admissible $\epsilon$). So can you prove that this is the case, and do you see that hence the support of $g$ is a compact subset of $V$?

Comment: something doesn't match, do you mean to use cardinalities of the sets involved as in the following formula: $g(x)=\frac{|V_\epsilon\cap B_\epsilon(x)|}{|B_\epsilon|}$? Are you trying to do something like in the following questions (showing every metric space is normal)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208752/proving-every-metric-space-is-normal

Comment: @Mirko I'm rather sure that $\lvert M\rvert$ here denotes the (Lebesgue) measure of $M$. I'm not a fan of that notation, but it's fairly widespread, and in this context it's the only interpretation I can think of that makes the approach work.

Comment: @DanielFischer The support is compact since this is contained in the closure of $V_{2\epsilon}$ and it is contained in $V$?

Comment: Yes. Can you prove that now?

Comment: To prove the continuity: I take two points $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^N$ s.t. $|x-y|<\delta<\epsilon$, and I want to show that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon '$. I use triangle inequality to bound the difference of measures but I don't know how to conclude

Comment: That's the right idea. But before considering the measures, think about how the sets $V_{\epsilon} \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)$ and $V_{\epsilon} \cap B_{\epsilon}(y)$ differ when $x$ and $y$ are close to each other. Again a sketch can help.

Comment: To prove the inequality you should be noticed that the function $g(x)$ is always less or equal to 1, and if you computed the set of points that are in the support. Also for the other inequality, what is the measure of $\mu(V_{\epsilon} \cap B_{\epsilon})$ in the set K.

Comment: I am not able to prove the continuity of $g$. I do the following: Let $x_n \to x$, then $$g(x_n)-g(x)=\frac{1}{|B_\epsilon|} |(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x_n))-(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x))|=\frac{1}{|B_\epsilon|} |V_\epsilon  \cap B_\epsilon(x_n)) \setminus B_\epsilon(x))| \\ \leq \frac{1}{|B_\epsilon|} |B_\epsilon(x_n)) \setminus B_\epsilon(x))|$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to a point (in your Oct 20 at 9:37 comment) when you need to show that $|B_\epsilon(x_n)) \setminus B_\epsilon(x))|\to0$ as $x_n\to x$. But, I don't quite see how you came to 
$|B_\epsilon(x_n)) \setminus B_\epsilon(x))|$.
(I think it is right, but the steps shown are not clear).
You started your comment with 
$g(x_n)-g(x)=\frac{1}{|B_\epsilon|} |(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x_n))-(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x))|$ and I would think that one should instead write 
$g(x_n)-g(x)=\frac{1}{|B_\epsilon|}\Bigl(|(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x_n))|-|(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x))|\Bigl)$. In addition to this correction, the LHS should be $|g(x_n)-g(x)|$, so $|g(x_n)-g(x)|=\frac{1}{|B_\epsilon|}|\Bigl(|(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x_n))|-|(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x))|\Bigl)|$ (where some of the vertical bars denote measure, and some absolute value).

Ultimately you need to show that when $y$ is close to $x$ then the measure 
$|V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(y)|$ is close to the measure $|V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x)|$.

Consider the case when $|V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(y)|\ge|V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x)|$ (the other case being symmetric to this one).

Then $0\le|V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(y)|-|V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x)|\le$
$\le|V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(y)|-|(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(y))\cap(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x))|=$
$=|(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(y))\setminus(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x))|=$
$=|V_\epsilon \cap (B_\epsilon(y)\setminus B_\epsilon(x))|\le$
$\le|B_\epsilon(y)\setminus B_\epsilon(x)|$.

Now, it should be obvious that $|B_\epsilon(y)\setminus B_\epsilon(x)|\to0$ 
as $y\to x$. I believe this might have been what @DanielFischer had in mind when he suggested making a sketch, in an Oct 19 at 12:45 comment. A picture in the plane is easy (and in $\Bbb R^3$ also easy enough). In the plane, the two balls (or disks) mostly overlap, except for two small "moons" (or crescents). The measure of these moons goes to $0$ (as $y\to x$). The formula for the volume $n$-dimensional ball is somewhat messy (if you would rather not rely on a picture), but it would be easier to come up with an estimate for the volume of each crescent, and one such estimate is the product of the norm $|x-y|$ with the "area" of the $(n-1)$-dimensional "disk". (I am using [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) for this estimate.) The area of $(n-1)$-dimensional disk in turn does not exceed the "area" of $(n-1)$-dimensional square with side-length the same as the diameter of $B_\epsilon$ (which is $2\epsilon$). 
Thus the area of such $(n-1)$-dimensional square with side-length $2\epsilon$ is 
$(2\epsilon)^{n-1}=2^{n-1}\epsilon^{n-1}$. 
The estimate for the volume of each crescent is $2^{n-1}\epsilon^{n-1}|x-y|$, 
and we have two crescent so the total volume estimate is 
$2^n\epsilon^{n-1}|x-y|$. Since $n$ and $\epsilon$ are fixed, we have that 
$2^n\epsilon^{n-1}|x-y|\to0$ as $y\to x$. (You may want to verify, and if necessary correct my estimates, to confirm that this approach works.)

Again, it helps to draw a picture.

Comment: Actually $|B_\epsilon(y)\setminus B_\epsilon(x)|$ is the measure of only one of the two moons, so I didn't have to multiply by $2$ at the end. Also, there are some extra closing parentheses on the second line of my answer, but I realize this is how they came from your comment :) will leave them as is.

Answer (score 0):

All claims except the continuity of $g$ are clear. For this, suppose $x_n\to x$, so 
$$
m(B_\epsilon) \lvert g(x_n) - g(x) \rvert = \lvert m( V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x_n)) - m(V_\epsilon \cap B_\epsilon(x)) \rvert \le m( V_\epsilon \cap (B_\epsilon(x_n) \mathbin{\square} B_\epsilon(x) ) ) \le 
m(B_\epsilon(x_n) \mathbin{\square} B_\epsilon(x)) =
m(B_\epsilon(x_n)) + m( B_\epsilon(x)) -2
m(B_\epsilon(x_n) \cap B_\epsilon(x)) = 2 (m( B_\epsilon(x)) - m(B_\epsilon(x_n) \cap B_\epsilon(x))
$$
Here I have written $\square$ for symmetric difference and used the inclusion exclusion principle. Hence the result will follow if we can prove that $m(B \cap (B+x)) \to m(B)$ as $x\to 0$. This follows from [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724411/continuity-of-measure-under-translation-in-mathbbrn).